# Handling Apollo-wrapped descendants in unit tests that mount the React component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, apollo, react-apollo

I've been working with ApolloJS in React (via `react-apollo`) for the past several months and have learned a number of the tricks and challenges associated with unit testing Apollo-wrapped components.

When testing a component that is directly wrapped with Apollo, I export and test the component before it is wrapped with HoC returned by `graphql`. When testing a component that has an Apollo-wrapped component as a descendant, I use Enzyme's `shallow` rendering whenever possible to prevent that descendant from mounting. If full-DOM rendering via `mount` is required, I use a `MockedProvider` from Apollo's test utils so that the descendants don't throw an error trying to access `this.context`.

I have not found a solution, however, for the following case: a component with Apollo-wrapped descendants needs to be tested using full-DOM rendering but I also need to make assertions involving the component instance (e.g. state, instance methods, etc). To avoid issues with descendants, I have to wrap the component in a mocked provider, but that means than any assertions on the `wrapper` are operating on the `MockedProvider` instance and not the component I want to be testing.

An example:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/lib/test-utils'

// This component has descendants that are wrapped in Apollo and
// thus need access to `this.context` provided by an Apollo provider
import Assignments from 'app/components/assignments

...

describe('<Assignments />', function() {
  it('sets sorted assignments in initial state', function() {
    const assignments = [...]

    const wrapper = mount(
      <MockedProvider>
        <Assignments assignments={assignments} />
      </MockedProvider>
    )

    // This will fail because the wrapper is of the MockedProvider
    // instance, not the Assignments instance
    expect(wrapper.state('assignments')).to.eql([...])
  })
})
```

I've tried to find a way via Enzyme to access the component instance of a child rather than the root, which as far as I can tell is not supported. I've also been trying to find alternatives to needing the `MockedProvider` in these tests but have not found anything yet.

Has anyone figured out a workaround for this sort of situation, or is there a different approach I should be taking to deal with nested Apollo-wrapped components?

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution to my problem. The reason Apollo-wrapped descendants of mounted components were causing problems is that they would throw an error when trying to access `this.context.client`. Apollo's `MockedProvider` creates an Apollo client (or optionally uses one you provide) and makes it available to its children via context.

Turns out Enzyme's `mount` method allows you to specify the component's [context](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html#-mount-node-options-reactwrapper). I had tried using that before, but didn't realize that I also needed to combine it with the [childContextTypes](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html#-mount-node-options-reactwrapper) for that context to be passed down to the mounted component's descendants. Using these Enzyme options avoids the need to use the `MockProvider`.

I'll demonstrate the solution based off the example provided in my original question:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

// This is an Apollo client I configured in a separate module
// with a mocked network interface. I won't go into details on
// that here, but am happy to provide more details if someone asks
import mockedClient from 'test/mocked_client'

// This component has descendants that are wrapped in Apollo and
// thus need access to `this.context` provided by an Apollo provider
import Assignments from 'app/components/assignments

...

describe('<Assignments />', function() {
  it('sets sorted assignments in initial state', function() {
    const assignments = [...]

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Assignments assignments={assignments} />,
      {
        context: { client: mockedClient },
        childContextTypes: {
          client: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
        }
      }
    )

    // This now passes!
    expect(wrapper.state('assignments')).to.eql([...])
  })
})
```

Hopefully this helps someone who finds themselves in a similar situation!